# How to implement a slider and replace a static image which overlays objects

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

OK, my site is instant-legaladvice.co.uk and the page i want to sort out is /conveyancing.php. As you can see, the page has a static image at the top (of a house).

I would love to turn this into a rotating slider but am really not sure of how to implement this... as the 'blue conveyancing box' / enquiry form overlap and would need to sit on top (as they do with the static image)

At present it looks something like this...

```
<section id="contentInner">
  <article class="conveyancing"><!-- content section -->
    <aside class="leaseExLeft">
      <aside class="newthird">
        <h3 class="red allcolor"><b>Conveyancing</b></h3>
        <aside class="text-block">
          <h5 class="colorwill"><b>From Just £75 + VAT</b></h5>
          <aside class="newthirdMenu">
            <ul>
              <li>Special Low Fixed Fees</a></li>
              <li>Fast Service</a></li>
              <li>Solicitor's Advice</a></li>
            </ul>
          </aside>
        </aside>
        <aside class="image-block"> <img alt="Conveyancing Block Image - Photo of Roof and Money Low cost service" img src="image/conveyancing_icon_alt.gif"  width="125px" height="138px" alt="featured"> </aside>
      </aside>
    </aside>
```

In CSS:

```
#contentInner{ 
    width:982px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    background:#fff;
    padding:10px 15px 10px 3px;
}

.conveyancing{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:30px;
    background: url(../image/conveyancing.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat; height:257px;
}
```

But I don't want a static image I want a rotating one!

Answer (score 0):

Quick Google search and you have your answer.

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3881826